# PHP registered user check

Tags: php

I have PHP + AS3 user login&register modul.I want to check registered user by username.But can't do it because I'm new at PHP.If you can help it will helpfull thx.(result_message part is my AS3 info text box.)

```
<?php 



include_once("connect.php");



$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$userbio = $_POST['userbio'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_bio) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$userbio')";

mysql_query($sql) or exit("result_message=Error");

exit("result_message=success.");                  



?>
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely, by fundamentally separating the data from the command.

Comment: Nothing in this code appears to be *attempting* to validate the user, so I'm not sure why you have pasted it here. This site isn't really the right place to ask for people to write your code from scratch, you need to show us what you have written so far, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Refrain from using `mysql_*` in NEW code, it's officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Instead, you should be using [mysqli_*](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) or [PDO](http://uk1.php.net/PDO). See a comparison of said APIs [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) as your PHP function.  Start there, it's safer.

Connect your DB -

```
$host = "////";
$user = "////";
$pass = "////";
$dbName = "////";

$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbName);
if($db->connect_errno){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . 
          $db->connect_errno . "<br>";
}
```

If you are getting the information from the form -

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$userbio = $_POST['userbio'];
```

you can query the DB and check the username and password  -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

If you get something back -

```
if($result) {
    //CHECK PASSWORD TO VERIFY
} else {
    echo "No user found.";
}
```

then verify the password.  You could also attempt to verify the username and password at the same time in your MySQL query like so -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password';
```

@Brad is right, though.  You should take a little more precaution when writing this as it is easily susceptible to hacks. This is a pretty good starter guide - http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: I think there is still a security hole if charset is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO is a good start, your connect.php should include something like the following:

```
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host','dbname=name','mysql_username','mysql_password');
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
```

Your insert would go something like:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$userbio = $_POST['userbio'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, user_bio) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

$std = $db->prepare($sql);

$std = execute(array($username, $password, $userbio));
```

To find a user you could query similarly setting your $username manually of from $_POST:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

$std = $db->prepare($query)

$std = execute($username); 

$result = $std->fetchAll();

if($result) {
    foreach ($result as $user) { print_r($user); }
} else { echo "No Users found."; }
```

It is important to [bind your values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), yet another guide for reference, since I do not have enough rep yet to link for each PDO command directly from the manual, [this guide and website](http://webdevelopingcat.com/php-mysql-tutorial-for-beginners-connecting-to-the-database-with-pdo/) has helped me out a lot with PHP and PDO.

Comment: I can't add new user with this way.And my post add same user again and again.(it is my main problem)

Comment: What is your http form's action? If your insert continually adds the same user repeatedly you could try using unsetting $_POST after you have already used the user's input.